# Display MVC message on start running

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im writing a script, i want to display a message to the view and then start my action. But its not showing anything, because my executing is blocking my startmessage. I dont want to use jquery/javascript.

Im trying this in my home/index controller

```
    return View(model: "Synck started, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 
    HH:mm:ss"));
```

In my view

```
       <div id="txt">
           @Model       // Synck started, 2015-10-10 10:10:10
           @Html.Action("Start", "Home")
       </div>
```

Comment: And why you don't want to use jquery/javascript ? I am curious

Comment: Its started on a server without javascripts etc. Used jQuery before but had to manually start it every month. I am synking 13GB of data so i thought a startmessage would be fine.

Comment: javascript/jquery is on client side. See the answer i posted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

The Controller::

```
// GET: Home/Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Synck started, " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    return View();
}
```

The View:

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you should be doing is keeping your long running code to a separate method and asynchronously invoke it from your UI. You may use jQuery `ajax` to do this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
public ActionResult SyncMydata()
{
   //Execute your long running code here and return something as needed.
}
```

And in your Index view,

```
<div id="status"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

   var url="@Url.Action("SyncMydata","Home")";

   $("#status").html("Started syncing at "+new Date().toLocaleString());
   $.post(url,function(res){
      $("#status").html("Sync completed"));
   });


 });
</script>
```

If you want, you can get the start time from the Index action(server side) rather than using the javascript time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to send the message that you want to display and ready for ViewData

Your Controller :

```
controllerName () 
{
    ViewData["Message"] ="Synck started, " +       DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 
      HH:mm:ss";

return View();
}
```

Your View:

```
<div id="txt">
          @ViewData["Message"]      // Synck started, 2015-10-10 10:10:10
           @Html.Action("Start", "Home")
       </div>
```

Comment: Same result, i think i email out my synkstart instead. Cant get it to work without jquery.

Comment: your answer does nothing different comparing to question

Comment: But the answer above was exactly what I meant